# Numpy set absolute value in place

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

You have an array A, and you want to turn every value in it as an absolute value. The problem is

```
numpy.abs(A)
```

creates a new matrix, and the values in A stay where they were. I find two ways to set put the absolute values back to A

```
A *= numpy.sign(A)
```

or

```
A[:] = numpy.abs(A)
```

Based on timeit test, their performance is almost the same
[image]

Question:

> Are there more efficient ways to perform this task?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an `out` parameter, which updates the array in-place:

```
numpy.abs(A, out=A)
```

And also happens to be a *lot* faster because you don't have to allocate memory for a new array.

```
A = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)

%timeit np.abs(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.9 ms per loop

%timeit np.abs(A, out=A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 647 µs per loop
```